# Records by unique id and on a per minute boundary

Tags: mysql

In a mysql database table below, I have records as shown below. I have data for many ID's. In the given example, I want to be able to get the first record in the list which has the least distance value. Additionally, I have an entire timeline of such data for many hours. So the goal is that for each MINUTE in the timeline, I want to be able to pick records for each unique ID in that minute with the lowest distance value. I know it's going to take a couple of good group by queries with join's but I've been unable to come up with something. Please help!!

```
| NAME    | ID    | TIME                    | TOTAL_TIME | DISTANCE        
| chicago | 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:39 GMT | 54         | 5        
| new york| 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:51 GMT | 42         | 3        
| chicago | 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:41 GMT | 56         | 11        
| chicago | 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:52 GMT | 67         | 12        
| new york| 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:53 GMT | 44         | 8        
| new york| 74    | 2017-02-26 23:17:56 GMT | 47         | 8
```

Comment: Is there a PK in this table?

Comment: No, this table has no PK....sorry!

Comment: I just added a PK in the table if it helps with the query. I'm unable to get the results on a per minute boundary.

Comment: Please update your sample data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> for each MINUTE in the timeline, I want to be able to pick records for each unique ID in that minute with the lowest distance value.

Kudos for expressing your SQL needs in clear English. First we need to decide on a GROUP BY key, which truncates a DATETIME down to the minutes. Unfortunately, MySQL has very bad datetime manipulation functions, so I'll use a kludge: convert to a string.

```
mysql> select LEFT(now(),16);
+------------------+
| LEFT(now(),16)   |
+------------------+
| 2017-04-01 21:15 |
+------------------+
```

Now, a self join will give the rows that contain the minimum distance. Note that if several rows contain the same minimum distance, they will all be returned.

```
SELECT t.* FROM
( SELECT id, LEFT(time, 16) AS minute, 
         min(distance) distance FROM yourtable 
  GROUP BY LEFT(time, 16), id ) a
JOIN yourtable t USING (id, distance)
```

This should do the trick...

Comment: Wow, I don't understand half of what the query is doing but I'm going to give this a try and share the results in a little. Thanks much.

Comment: OK. This is working great. But I just discovered that I need one more thing. The query returns multiple records for the ID if I have the same TOTAL_TIME value. In this case, I need to be able to pick the record with the highest TOTAL_TIME. Is there a way to modify this query to do just that?

Comment: You can do it in SQL but the simplest way is to use an ORDER BY  and then, in your application, only take the first row and throw away the next ones in the group.

Comment: I was hoping to do this in SQL. If I create a new table using this query, is there a simpler query on the new table to extract out the ones with the max total_time value?

Comment: If you only select id, distance, total_time and (id, distance) are identical in each group then SELECT max(total_time) GROUP BY id, distance

Comment: This worked for a small dataset but when I tried it on my close to a million records, I ended up having 145 million records and I see a ton of duplicates. What could be happening?

Comment: That's because I'm an idiot and I forgot to add the time range in the join. Could you post an excerpt of your table on a file sharing website? I'd like to try something with session variables...

Comment: Sure, can I do this to your e-mail? Can you share your mail id with me please?

Comment: hmmmm this site has no PMs and I won't put it in public for all spambots to harvest, lol

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the autoincrementing PK column is called `id_pk` in your table, you can find id_pk for each id and minute using a correlated subquery with `limit`.

```
select t.*
from your_table t
where id_pk = (
        select id_pk
        from your_table s
        where t.id = s.id
            and unix_timestamp(s.time) div 300
                = unix_timestamp(t.time) div 300
        order by distance limit 1
        )
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/TSGTBT97062)

`unix_timestamp(s.time) div 300` is to truncate the datetime to within 5 minutes (5 x 60 = 300 seconds).

Comment: Great! This may really work an my initial testing is going well. How would I modify this query for say 5 mins instead of the 1 min interval?

Comment: that's really not returning records on a 5 min interval. I'm still seeing 1 min interval records.

Comment: @Beacon No. It is working correctly. See this - http://rextester.com/JEPK28068 . It groups 5 mins like - 12:00, 12:05, 12:10, ... so on. and finds min distance records in that group for each id.

Comment: Hmm...could it be because my time fields are actually string values and not date/time fields? Can I do something to convert it to date/time before using it?

Comment: @BeaconHunter - It works correctly even with string value. See this - http://rextester.com/MKDQ81950

Comment: I tried running this on my dataset of 800K records and the query has been running for a few hours now and is not done. This is obviously not a quick enough solution unfortunately. Is there anything else I can do or have I hit a wall?